# Quartz Scheduler Job Auto Termination

Tags: quartz-scheduler

How do I create a Quartz Scheduler job that terminates automatically after given amount of time (if running job takes too much time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Quartz scheduler has no built-in functionality to interrupt a job by itself after a given amount of time.

If you dont want to interrupt Jobs (see the interface InterruptableJob) manually (for example with rmi), you could easily establish such a automatically termination.

Either:

1. When starting a scheduler, fork a deamon-thread that runs periodically and checks whether some of the currently running jobs must be interrupted. For Example you could use a JobDataMap to store the maximum execution time on a per job instance basis.
2. Each Job could control its maximum execution time in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

To stop a job from the inside of the job itself the easiest way is to throw an exception after a specific amount of time. For example:

```
public class MyJob : IJob
{
    Timer _t;

    public MyJob()
    {
        TimeSpan maxRunningTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        _t = new Timer(delegate { throw new JobExecutionException("took to long"); }, null, (int) maxRunningTime.TotalMilliseconds,
            -1);
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        // do your word
        // destroy T before leaving

        _t = null;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)